# Enabling Label on Userform by choosing Element out of Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to enable some Labels on my Userform by choosing the fourth Element out of a Combobox.

I've tried it with a Button. But when trying it with a Combobox nothing is happening.

'Sub with Button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Label5.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

'My best try so far with the Combobox

```
Private Sub cmbox1_Click()
  If Me.cmbox1.ListIndex = 3 Then
    Label5.Enabled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

How to make it work using the combobox?

Comment: Could you show/edit the code by which you are adding your combobox list? Are you possibly filtering the choices by keypresses so that the listindices would change, too?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `_Change()` event handler, not the `_Click()` one. So your code should be:

```
Private Sub cmbox1_Change()
  If Me.cmbox1.ListIndex = 3 Then
    Label5.Enabled = True
  End If
End Sub
```